# Django form not showing fields in correct order

Tags: python, django, forms

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. The fields are mentioned in order. Still i get different order of the fields everytime i restart the django server. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJm2V.png).

views.py

```
def user_creation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            return render(request, 'info/base.html')

    else:
        user_form = UserRegForm()

    context = {
        'UserForm' : user_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/form.html', context )
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = { 'username', 'password1','password2' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `set` which is inherently unordered:

```
fields = {'username', 'password1', 'password2'}
```

Make it a `list` or `tuple`:

```
fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
```